# Blazor - render content of facebook/meta page-plugin

Tags: facebook, blazor-server-side

I have entire new blazor - server-side project and I want to add page plugin from facebook/meta like here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/).
The content is not loaded correctly - I see only text link.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEp1m.png)

I suspect that problem have base "OnAfterRender". I spent few hours to try make it work, but without success.

in _Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace fbpage.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="fbpage.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v17.0" nonce="EvlRPiZT"></script>
    
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

In index.cshtml

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

Have I include this generated code in different pages etc. _Host.cshtml or how correctly use JSRuntime.InvokeAsync ... to make it work?

Comment: For content that was not part of the document already when the SDK initialized, you need to explicitly trigger the parsing. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe some example can help. So what I have written is OK, but I need to manually Invoke fb-sdk javascript to initialize it?

Comment: You need to call the method I linked to, after the element(s) you want to be replaced with social plugins, have been inserted into your page. (How to wait for/catch that moment within your setup, I don't know, that's for you to figure out.)